# Inline image shown as attachment : JavaMail

Tags: java, gmail, jakarta-mail

I am trying to send an email with an inline image, but the image is getting send as an attachment instead of inline.

```
 MimeMessage mimeMessage = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();
    try {
        String filename = "logo.jpeg";

        mimeMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress("Bridge"));
        mimeMessage.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
        mimeMessage.setSubject(subject);

        MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        messageBodyPart.setContent(content, "text/html");

        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
        messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

        DataSource fds = new ByteArrayDataSource(IOUtils.toByteArray(resourceFile.getInputStream()), MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE);
        messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds));
        messageBodyPart.setDisposition(MimeBodyPart.INLINE);
        messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename);
        messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-ID", "<logoimg>");
        messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-Type", MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE);

        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

        mimeMessage.setContent(multipart);
        mimeMessage.saveChanges();

        javaMailSender.send(mimeMessage);
   }  catch (MailException | MessagingException | IOException e) {
        log.warn("Email could not be sent to user '{}'", to, e);
   }
```

And here is my HTML code for the image:

```
<img width="100" height="50" src="|cid:logoimg|" alt="phoenixlogo"/>
```

I have tried all the multipart types: "mixed", "relative", "alternative" but couldn't get it to work.

Here is image for same:[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want an inline image, you want an html body that references an attached image.  For that you need a multipart/related message.  See the [JavaMail FAQ](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#sendmpr).

Comment: I tried suggestions provided you but in that case, the image does appear at desktop and mobile Gmail client but when I try to view mail in browser of any mobile then the image broke. Can you please tell me what could be the reason behind that?

Comment: How are you viewing the message in the browser?  Are you using the Gmail web user interface on your mobile device browser?  If it displays in the Gmail mobile app, I would expect that it would display in the Gmail web UI as well.

Comment: That's the issue here. The image is displaying in the Gmail mobile app but not in Gmail web UI as well. I have tried this in different mobile's Gmail UI but couldn't succeed (I have used chrome browser for this).

Comment: If you use the GMail app to send a similar type of message and then examine that message for its structure, you should be able construct a similarly structured message using JavaMail.

Comment: I tried to send a similar message with the Gmail app and ended up having the same issue in the browser so it seems like it's Gmail's issue not the code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a separate `MimeBodyPart`: For Example

```
            BodyPart imgPart = new MimeBodyPart();

            DataSource ds = new FileDataSource("D:/image.jpg");
            imgPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(ds));
            imgPart.setHeader("Content-ID", "<the-img-1>");
            multipart.addBodyPart(imgPart);
```

Then in the html you refer to the Image as:

```
<br>" + "<img src=\"cid:the-img-1\"/><br/>
```

Comment: I am already doing that: messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart(); and content-id also.

Comment: You are already using that BodyPart for the message, you need to have a separate one for the image and add it to the multipart.

Comment: I am reinstating that object again here and I have tried with creating a whole new object with new BodyPart as well.